# How to index TRUE elements in a vector in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector

```
A=[1,3, 4, 5]

logical = [TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE]
```

How do I index TRUE elements so that it returns 1 and 3?

In matlab you can do things like  `A(logical)` or `A(~logical)`

What is equivalent syntax for R?

Comment: When defining a vector in R, you use the `c` ("concatenate") function.  So it should be `A <- c(1, 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: I've upvoted this because I think 8 downvotes is a bit harsh. This might be a very, very basic question but the question is clear, which is much better than some other questions I see here.

Comment: I disagree.  I sometimes think we need a type of captcha test...

Comment: Agree with Sacha. He/she explains the question clearly. Anyone who thinks it is simple just skip it. so I upvoted the question.

Comment: I upvoted it as well. When switching between programming languages you sometimes forget the correct syntax, and rather than looking through the R documentation again, I'd rather do a quick Google Search (which lead me to this question). The question is clear, well formulated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`A[logical]` does the trick.

This is in [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Comment: Ouch is way too mellow for this.

Comment: Yes, this is a very basic question.  I know a little of bit of Matlab and I am learning R so sometimes I get the 2 programming language confused.  Anyway, thank you for your comments.  ;-)